# rails and ajax request 404 error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have this error on my rails logs :

```
Completed 404 Not Found in 11ms
** [Raven] User excluded error: #<ActionController::RoutingError: Not Found>

ActionController::RoutingError (Not Found):
  app/controllers/schools_controller.rb:6:in `common_content'
```

I don't understand why, here is the code :

**Show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Vérifiés (#{@count_verified})", rate_verified_path, remote: true %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
get '/rate_verified' => 'schools#verified_rating'
```

**schools_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :common_content, :only => [:show, :verified_rating]

def verified_rating
  @selected = @ratings.where(:verified => true)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

**verified_rating.js.erb**

```
$('#verifie').html("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'rating') %>");
```

Does someone could help me ?

**EDIT**

the common_content method :

```
def common_content
  @school = School.where(city_namespace: params[:city], title_namespace: params[:title]).first || raise(ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found'))
  @rating = Rating.new(params[:rating])
  @rating.school_id = @school.id
  @ratings = @school.ratings.desc(:created_at)
end
```

Comment: How does the method `:common_content` look like? Can you show it's code?

Answer (score 2):

In first line of `common_content` method, we can see:

```
  School.where(city_namespace: params[:city], title_namespace: params[:title]).first || raise(ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found'))
```

Because the first part (before `||`) of that code returns `nil` the second part is executed, which is:

```
    raise(ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
```

So the 404 is raised because no `School` record was found.

Comment: How can I have a record available ?

Comment: I don't understand because when I put `<%= @school.title %>` in the view, I have a response, but why I have a `nil` response in the :common_content method ?

Comment: That means, that you have the School record in database. Pass `city` and `title` params to the ajax request, so it can be found.

Comment: The request where view is rendered and the ajax request are two separate requests. In the first request `School` is found because your code can "see" the `city` and `title` params, whereas the ajax request not.

Comment: ok I understand, but now, do you know how could I access these informations in the ajax request ?

Comment: Once you will have those params available, you can access them through `params` object (easy). The hard part would be to pass them to the request. You could do it through `get` params, like `get '/rate_verified?title=...&city=...'` but it can generate encoding problems. You could change `get` to `post` and pass them as post params. Or you could follow the REST guides and change the route to `get '/rate_verified/:school_id'` and query the `School` record in controller by its id.

Comment: I try that in routes.rb `  get '/verified_rating/:school_id' => 'schools#verified_rating', as: :verified_rating` adding this line in the verified_rating method : `@school = School.find(:school_id)` but I have this error : `Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms
** [Raven] User excluded error: #<Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound:
message:
  Document(s) not found for class School with id(s) school_id.
`